# TFS 2010 Link Extensibility

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, extensibility

I found this article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narend/archive/2006/10/13/how-to-extend-linking-and-workitem-ui-with-custom-link-types.aspx) about link extensibility in TFS 2005.  I'm wondering how to do this in TFS 2010/Visual Studio 2010. It doesn't look like the dll Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll exists anymore, and this is where the IDialogControl interface was located.

How are you supposed to do this in TFS 2010?

Comment: You are not asking how to create new or modify existing link types defined by the Process Template, right?

Comment: No, what I'm actually trying to do is find a way to attach git checkins to TFS work items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That DLL can be found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`